# SyntaxError: UNexpected token n

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I'm learning how to use the MEAN stack and to practice I'm doing a web that ask you for your name, your email and a course you've done recently. Then it stores the information to a DB. I can't find the error and maybe is an easy one.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = require('./user');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost');

app.use(morgan('dev'));

var apiRouter = express.Router();
apiRouter.route('/')
.post(function(req, res) {
    var user = new User();
    user.name = req.body.name;
    user.course = req.body.course;
    user.mail = req.res.mail;
    user.save(function(err) {
        console.log(user.name);
        res.json({ message: 'Thank you!'});
    });
}).get(function(req, res) {
    User.find(function(err, users) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json(users);
    });
    res.json({ message: 'YEAAAAHHHH!'});
});

app.use('/', apiRouter);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port' + port);
```

And this is the user.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    course: {type: String, required: true},
    mail: {type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Thank you! :D

EDIT: sorry I forgot to put the error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token n
at parse (/Users/pingu/Documents/mean_project/node_modules/body-parser /lib/types/json.js:83:15)
at /Users/pingu/Documents/mean_project/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
at invokeCallback (/Users/pingu/Documents/mean_project/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
at done (/Users/pingu/Documents/mean_project/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/pingu/Documents/mean_project/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:308:7)
at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:474:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:388:17)
```

Comment: Could you also post your error?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah sorry  cc/ @The

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Unexpected token` is an error message produced by `JSON.parse`, so you are

1. telling your server to expect JSON, and
2. not supplying valid JSON.

This is because you supply a `Content-type: application/json` header in your request, but you're supplying form-type urlencoded data in your body like `name=foobar&course=baz&...`

Simply remove the JSON `Content-type` so your server will parse the body correctly as form data.

Comment: I see. I'm using Postman and this is what I do:
https://gyazo.com/20074774913ddf445538e62c562dcc2b
So should I put "name" instead of name? Because I'm getting an error too.

Comment: @xampla Ah, in that case, your problem is that you are sending `x-www-form-urlencoded` data formatted like `name=foobar&course=....` but for some reason your app is trying to parse it as JSON. You aren't setting the header `Content-Type: application/json` in your request, are you?

Comment: @xampla Yes, don't do that, because you're not sending JSON. If you were doing that, that was causing your problem.

Comment: ok but now when I try to get the users I get this error https://gyazo.com/f03ed9db86a422e7ffa5b63b9bc12fbc related with headers

Comment: @xampla That's because you're calling `res.json` twice, but `res.json` finalizes the HTTP response (so you can't call it twice, because on the second call, the response is already finished.) that's a completely separate issue and is fixed by simply not calling `res.json` more than once per execution of your `.get` handler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104321/discussion-between-xampla-and-apsillers).

Comment: @apsillers I have the same problem - when I removed the header - parser don`t see any content (I use multipart/form-data) - request.body is empty.